# nmake.exe: is there a way to exclude a file from a set of files specified in a macro?

Tags: windows, nmake

I'm looking for something like the [Exclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164283(VS.90).aspx) filter for msbuild, but I Want it in a makefile processed by nmake.

Is that possible?

Suppose I have a makefile that defines this macro:

```
SOURCES=xxx.c  yyy.c  zzz.c
```

and I invoke it with `nmake OLD=xxx.c NEW=bbb.c`

...can I produce, within the makefile, a macro with a value like:

```
yyy.c zzz.c  bbb.c
```

...basically substituting bbb.c for xxx.c ?

The files can appear in any order.

---

This would be pretty easy if the string substitution that is possible in nmake macros, allowed for evaluation of macros.

In other words, I can do

```
sources=xxx.c yyy.c zzz.c
objs=$(sources:.c=.o)
```

and the value of $(objs) is

```
xxx.o yyy.o zzz.o
```

But [nmake does not allow a macro for the value of either argument to that substitution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71286).  I cannot do this:

```
new=.o
sources=xxx.c yyy.c zzz.c
objs=$(sources:.c=$(new))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do exactly what I wanted, but i found a workaround.

It involves something called ["inline files"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seaaew50.aspx) which are files that nmake creates dynamically and then uses in the command block.  In my case I used the "inline file" trick to create a .cmd file and run it.  The .cmd file did the include/exclude logic, and then ran the compiler on the massaged list of source files.

It looks like this.

```
  CSOURCE=Fribble.c Zambda.c Twoolie.c
         ....
  target :
          <<tmp-build-file.cmd  $(CSOURCE)
      SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
      for %%I in (%*) do if NOT %%I == $(EXC) (
         set filesToBuild=!filesToBuild! %%I
      )
      $(CC) $(INC) !filesToBuild!
      ENDLOCAL
  <<
```

To invoke that, you can do:

```
nmake INC=AdditionalFile.c  EXC=Zambda.c  target
```

...and it does the right thing: Compiles Fribble.c Twoolie.c and AdditionalFile.c, but not Zambda.c .